# Is there a way to flatten a json list with snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column that is a list in my table I'd like to flatten/expand to columns so I can transform it from this

`{"name a":1,"name b":1,"name c":1,"name d":1,"name e":1}`

To this

`|name a |name b|name c|name d |name e|`

`| 1     |1     |1     |1      |1    |`

Where each is its own column

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a dynamic way of doing this. Whether you flatten and then Pivot the columns back up or do it in this way below, you will need to reference the column names. There might be a way to dynamically do this in a stored procedure or dynamically create the SQL in Python or another language:

```
-- Creating a Mock table to query
WITH json_table AS (
  SELECT TO_VARIANT(PARSE_JSON('{"name a":1,"name b":1,"name c":1,"name d":1,"name e":1}')) AS json_field
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT TO_VARIANT(PARSE_JSON('{"name a":2,"name b":2,"name c":2,"name d":2,"name e":2}')) AS json_field

)

SELECT json_field:"name a" AS "name a"
      ,json_field:"name b" AS "name b"
      ,json_field:"name c" AS "name c"
      ,json_field:"name d" AS "name d"
      ,json_field:"name e" AS "name e"
FROM json_table j
;
```

Answer (score 0):

create or replace table test222(src variant)

as

select parse_json(column1) as src

from values('{"name a":1,"name b":1,"name c":1,"name d":1,"name e":1}')

select src:"name a" as "name a",src:"name b" as "name b",src:"name c" as "name c",src:"name d" as "name d",src:"name e" as "name e"  from test222